# Http authentication with Zend

Tags: php, http, zend-framework

I want to do a http auth with zend, I read that article http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html but I dont think its valuable (why the heck are the password taken from an external file...?).
I know it can simply be done with headers:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=sdfsdf');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
die;
```

but since we are using Zend, I would like to convert it:

```
$response->setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="asda"', true);
$response->setHeader('Status', '401 Unauthorized', true);
```

it wont accept it, nothing happens. Even if it works, I cant use `die();` right after this. Can somebody show a way out?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use the File resolver. You can write your own resolver class, by simply extending the Zend_Auth_Adapter_Http_Resolver_Interface:

```
class MyOwnResolver implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Http_Resolver_Interface
{
    /**
     * Resolve username/realm to password/hash/etc.
     *
     * @param  string $username Username
     * @param  string $realm    Authentication Realm
     * @return string|false User's shared secret, if the user is found in the
     *         realm, false otherwise.
     */
    public function resolve($username, $realm)
    {
        if ($username == 'testUser' && $realm == 'testPassword') {
            return $realm;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/* In your controller */

$config = array(
    'accept_schemes' => 'basic',
    'realm'          => 'My Realm',
    'nonce_timeout'  => 3600,
);
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Http($config);
$result = $adapter->setBasicResolver(new MyOwnResolver())
        ->setRequest($this->getRequest())
        ->setResponse($this->getResponse())
        ->authenticate();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code example, can you give a example for the request structure?

Comment: you need to find out how to implement basic auth with the particular client you are using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623768/authentication-using-zend-http-client may help if you are using Zend_Http_Client

Answer (score 0):

Example with a sample action controller:

```
    public function preDispatch() {

        if (
            !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) 
            || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) 
            || 'admin' != $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] 
            || 'admin' != $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
        ) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Authentication required"');
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(401);
            if ('not-auth' !== $this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
                $this->_forward('not-auth');
            }
        }
    }

    public function indexAction() { }

    public function notAuthAction() { }

}
```

This clever solution was found here.
https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/1148691